# Find the limit of $(a_k)_k$ where $a_k = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{m=1}^{kn} \mathrm{exp}(\frac12.\frac{m^2}{n^2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, gre-exam

For $k \ge 1$, let $$a_k = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{m=1}^{kn} e^{\frac12.\frac{m^2}{n^2}}$$ Find the value of $$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k$$

Comment: Each $a_k$ is a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). See also [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: Also, you forgot a minus sign inside the exponent.

Comment: @Lucian, there is no minus sign.

Comment: If there isn't one, then the sum diverges. But if there is one, then it converges to $\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}$

Comment: Thank you @Lucian. I'll check again then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{m=1}^{kn}e^{^{-\tfrac12\cdot\tfrac{m^2}{n^2}}}=\int_0^ke^{^{-\frac{x^2}2}}dx\qquad=>\qquad\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=\int_0^\infty e^{^{-\frac{x^2}2}}dx=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$$